# Caching MVC .NET 4.0

Tags: model-view-controller, caching, .net-4.0

I am trying to cache a selectlist which is not null but I get a null exception error. The line of code causing the error is: (note item is created using Cache item = new Cache(); and tripVM.friendDropDown holds the selectlist

```
   item.Insert("friendDropDown", tripVM.friendDropDown,null,DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(10000), TimeSpan.Zero);
```

Most of the online resources say that I could use the syntax below but this is not allowed in VS2010 using .NET 4.0:

```
   cache["friendDropDown"] = tripVM.friendDropDown;
```

Where is this error coming from?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be caching that data and not the control.  Inside the controller, check if the cache exists otherwise add it.  Then you set the data to the ViewData or a Model you pass to the view and access it from there.

If your intention is to cache the entire view results then you can cache the output from the controller using "OutputCache" attribute.

Finally, when you go to cache something, you should be using HttpContext.Cache (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.cache.aspx) this will give you a single area to cache unless you want to create your own cache manager or use one like enterprise libarary.